# Laravel : difference between production path and local path ; need to use public/

Tags: laravel, path, hosting, font-awesome, production

I have a **path problem with Laravel on production**, while **everything works perfectly well locally**.

- Hosting service : Hostinger
- Laravel : 5.8

This concerns the relative paths used that **require, on production, to have `public/` in the path used by any resource**.

If I take the example of a CSS sheet, **locally**, I use the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

And on the **production**, I am obliged to add `public/` for the path otherwise the sheet is not detected:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}">
```

For now, I use a global variable (in the Controller class) that is used if the application is in production so that I don't have to make any changes in the code when I go into production : 
`href="{{ asset($public_prod.'css/style.css') }}"`.

But the problem is that I have to put this variable on all resources (images, CSS, JS...) because otherwise, the resource does not display.

**In addition**, some resources such as **font-awesome fonts do not load with the CSS sheet** which, even if detected, **only displays a unicode rectangle**. My solution isn't perfect...

**Note : my application works perfectly on Heroku service on production WITHOUT adding `public/` to resources paths, I don't know why it's not same on Hostinger service...**

Comment: you are put the all the css and js and other library in the public folder. and then run this code<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}">

Comment: and if you want to remove public folder in your url so you can make in helper.php file like write this code             function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}

Comment: If I use this solution, it's not working with local

Comment: Is your .htaccess working on hostinger? It seems your site only seems because there is an index.php in the `public` folder

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MaartenDev

The solution :

- Edit `.htaccess` at *root* directory of Laravel and replace all with :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Create a copy of `server.php` at *root* directory and rename it to `index.php`

localhost and production will works!